# Reshaping df from wide to long creating a new column with event names

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, reshape

I've got a data frame with data of different time points in which various event started and ended. The data frame looks something like this:

```
Date    Event 1 start   Event 1 end Event 2 start   Event 2 end Event 3 start   Event 3 end
01/01/2020  06:35   18:02   06:13   18:24   03:15   15:18
02/01/2020  06:36   18:02   06:13   18:24   04:02   15:57
03/01/2020  06:36   18:01   06:13   18:24   04:50   16:37
04/01/2020  06:36   18:01   06:14   18:24   05:39   17:21
05/01/2020  06:36   18:01   06:14   18:23   06:28   18:06
06/01/2020  06:37   18:01   06:14   18:23   07:18   18:54
07/01/2020  06:37   18:01   06:14   18:23   08:07   19:43
08/01/2020  06:37   18:01   06:15   18:23   08:56   20:34
09/01/2020  06:38   18:01   06:15   18:23   09:43   21:26
10/01/2020  07:38   19:01   07:15   19:23   10:43   22:26
11/01/2020  08:38   20:01   08:15   20:23   11:43   23:26
12/01/2020  09:38   21:01   09:15   21:23   12:43   00:26
```

And I would like to reshape it from wide to long creating a new "event" column so I am looking to get something like:

```
Date    Event   Start   End
01/01/2020  Event 1 06:24   18:10
01/01/2020  Event 2 18:10   18:54
01/01/2020  Event 3 18:54   23:59
02/01/2020  Event 1 06:24   18:10
02/01/2020  Event 2 18:10   18:54
02/01/2020  Event 3 18:54   23:59
03/01/2020  Event 1 06:24   18:10
03/01/2020  Event 2 18:10   18:54
03/01/2020  Event 3 18:54   23:59
04/01/2020  Event 1 06:24   18:10
04/01/2020  Event 2 18:10   18:54
04/01/2020  Event 3 18:54   23:59
```

I've tried using gather function from dplyr but it's not giving me the desired result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The names are a bit dirty, so a possible approach is to tidy them before pivoting.

```
tibble::tribble(
         ~Date, ~Event.1.start, ~Event.1.end, ~Event.2.start, ~Event.2.end, ~Event.3.start, ~Event.3.end,
  "01/01/2020",        "06:35",      "18:02",        "06:13",      "18:24",        "03:15",      "15:18",
  "02/01/2020",        "06:36",      "18:02",        "06:13",      "18:24",        "04:02",      "15:57",
  "03/01/2020",        "06:36",      "18:01",        "06:13",      "18:24",        "04:50",      "16:37",
  "04/01/2020",        "06:36",      "18:01",        "06:14",      "18:24",        "05:39",      "17:21",
  "05/01/2020",        "06:36",      "18:01",        "06:14",      "18:23",        "06:28",      "18:06",
  "06/01/2020",        "06:37",      "18:01",        "06:14",      "18:23",        "07:18",      "18:54",
  "07/01/2020",        "06:37",      "18:01",        "06:14",      "18:23",        "08:07",      "19:43",
  "08/01/2020",        "06:37",      "18:01",        "06:15",      "18:23",        "08:56",      "20:34",
  "09/01/2020",        "06:38",      "18:01",        "06:15",      "18:23",        "09:43",      "21:26",
  "10/01/2020",        "07:38",      "19:01",        "07:15",      "19:23",        "10:43",      "22:26",
  "11/01/2020",        "08:38",      "20:01",        "08:15",      "20:23",        "11:43",      "23:26",
  "12/01/2020",        "09:38",      "21:01",        "09:15",      "21:23",        "12:43",      "00:26"
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Date) %>%
  # create separation to be able to pivot wider using values from start and end 
  mutate(event = readr::parse_number(stringr::str_replace(pattern = "\\.", replacement="", string=name)),
         name = stringr::str_extract(name, pattern="start|end")) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Date, event), names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

This produces

```
# A tibble: 36 × 4
   Date       event start end  
   <chr>      <dbl> <chr> <chr>
 1 01/01/2020     1 06:35 18:02
 2 01/01/2020     2 06:13 18:24
 3 01/01/2020     3 03:15 15:18
 4 02/01/2020     1 06:36 18:02
 5 02/01/2020     2 06:13 18:24
 6 02/01/2020     3 04:02 15:57
 7 03/01/2020     1 06:36 18:01
 8 03/01/2020     2 06:13 18:24
 9 03/01/2020     3 04:50 16:37
10 04/01/2020     1 06:36 18:01
# … with 26 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Be aware that your given dataset might be slightly different. I had to clean them from a copy-paste of what you provided. If you provide the `str()` of your data, it might be easier, but the main ideas are here.

1. Pivot everything using the `Date`
2. Make new variables from variable `name`
3. Pivot wider, so that we can use the new columns to get names and values

Comment: Thanks very much! What if I wanted to keep the full name of each event instead of the number in the "event" column? I guess I'd need tweaking this bit of hte code 

(event = readr::parse_number(stringr::str_replace(pattern = "\\."

Comment: @RGR_288 it really depends on the actual names of your columns. In this case my column names were `Event.1.start` because you have spaces on your example names. To parse the number of the event, I chose to use `parse_number()`, but you could chose a different way. For example, you could first extract "start|end", and then remove them from the string to be left with an `Event.1` type of string. You could also put back the "Event", with something like `mutate(name = paste("Event", name))`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you.
The columns titles just need the "Event" part to end with a digit, a space/character, and then the final column titles (start & end, in this case).

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("01/01/2020", "02/01/2020", "03/01/2020", "04/01/2020", "05/01/2020", "06/01/2020", "07/01/2020", "08/01/2020", 
                        "09/01/2020", "10/01/2020", "11/01/2020", "12/01/2020"), 
                     `Event 1 start` = c("06:35",  "06:36", "06:36", "06:36", "06:36", "06:37", "06:37", "06:37", "06:38", "07:38", "08:38", "09:38"), 
                     `Event 1 end` = c("18:02", "18:02", "18:01", "18:01", "18:01", "18:01", "18:01", "18:01",  "18:01", "19:01", "20:01", "21:01"), 
                     `Event 2 start` = c("06:13", "06:13", "06:13", "06:14", "06:14", "06:14", "06:14", "06:15", "06:15", "07:15", "08:15", "09:15"), 
                     `Event 2 end` = c("18:24",  "18:24", "18:24", "18:24", "18:23", "18:23", "18:23", "18:23",  "18:23", "19:23", "20:23", "21:23"),
                     `Event 3 start` = c("03:15", "04:02", "04:50", "05:39", "06:28", "07:18", "08:07", "08:56", "09:43", "10:43", "11:43", "12:43"), 
                     `Event 3 end` = c("15:18", "15:57", "16:37", "17:21", "18:06", "18:54", "19:43", "20:34", "21:26", "22:26", "23:26", "00:26")), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -12L))

library(tidyr)
df %>% pivot_longer(-c(Date), names_pattern = "(.+\\d).(.+)", 
                     names_to = c("Event", ".value"))

 # A tibble: 36 × 4
   Date       Event   start end  
   <chr>      <chr>   <chr> <chr>
 1 01/01/2020 Event 1 06:35 18:02
 2 01/01/2020 Event 2 06:13 18:24
 3 01/01/2020 Event 3 03:15 15:18
 4 02/01/2020 Event 1 06:36 18:02
 5 02/01/2020 Event 2 06:13 18:24
 6 02/01/2020 Event 3 04:02 15:57
 7 03/01/2020 Event 1 06:36 18:01
 8 03/01/2020 Event 2 06:13 18:24
 9 03/01/2020 Event 3 04:50 16:37
10 04/01/2020 Event 1 06:36 18:01
# ℹ 26 more rows
```